# It has been developed

Tags: grammar, expressions, sentence-structure, passive-voice

Can someone tell me if this sentence is correct? If not, how could I arrange it?

"For these reasons, it has been developed and validated a program to predict..."

Comment: It _could_ be correct. You have to provide more context.

Comment: This works for me: "_... For these reasons, a program has been developed and validated in order to predict ..._". But mind you, this question is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use "dummy 'it'" in this sort of sentence.

You can however use "dummy 'there'", though it is a bit awkward. So

"There has been developed a program ... " is grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this sentence is that it contains both a pronoun and the noun that it should replace: something's got to go.

> For these reasons, **it** has been developed and validated **a program** to predict...

You can remove **a program**, as long as it is clear from the context that **it** is the program.

> For these reasons, **it** has been developed and validated to predict...

or you can get rid of **it** and move **a program** to its place:

> For these reasons, **a program** has been developed and validated to predict...